# Liferay 6.2-ce-ga2 clustering issue

Tags: solr, liferay, liferay-6, ehcache, solr4

Liferay 6.2-ce-ga2

I'm trying to cluster two nodes, I'm using tomcat liferay bundle for both the nodes.

I used the following blog post as a reference and many others 
https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/liferay-clustering

Both the nodes starts up as expected but they are not in sync. I dont have any errors on my console. I used the direct URL to login to a particular node and say, added an organization or published a web content article, which is not getting reflected when i login through the other node. Whatever I update through a particular node is only visible in that node.

Every change from both the nodes are getting updated in database.

**portal-ext.properties**

```
 dl.store.file.system.root.dir= /cmsdata

 cluster.link.enabled=true
 lucene.replicate.write=true


jdbc.default.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:1521:example
jdbc.default.username=username
jdbc.default.password=password
```

are there any configurations that Im missing...?

---

### **After a few configuration changes**

Im using

- **Liferay 6.2-ce-ga2**
- **solr4-web-6.2.0.3.war and**
- **solr-4.3.1**

After a few configuration changes Liferay and SOLR are now up and running.
SOLR is running on a seperate Tomcat.

Now if I start the liferay server and delete a user from the control panel, the user will be deleted and when i go back to *"Users and Organizations"* the system goes into an infinite loop (i could see that from SOLR console) and i will have to shutdown the Liferay server to get it out of the loop.

**Log**

```
2705809 [http-bio-8077-exec-9] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={fl=*&sort=lastName_sortable+asc&start=0&q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&facet.limit=-1&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=2} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
2705819 [http-bio-8077-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=0} hits=2 status=0 QTime=1
2705828 [http-bio-8077-exec-9] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2} {delete=[125_PORTLET_13232 (-1501157056068976640)]} 0 0
2705829 [http-bio-8077-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={fl=*&sort=lastName_sortable+asc&start=0&q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&facet.limit=-1&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=2} hits=2 status=0 QTime=1
2705839 [http-bio-8077-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2} {delete=[125_PORTLET_13232 (-1501157056080510976)]} 0 0
2705839 [http-bio-8077-exec-9] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=0} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
2705849 [http-bio-8077-exec-9] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={fl=*&sort=lastName_sortable+asc&start=0&q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&facet.limit=-1&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=2} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
2705859 [http-bio-8077-exec-9] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2} {delete=[125_PORTLET_13232 (-1501157056101482496)]} 0 0
2705859 [http-bio-8077-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=0} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
2705869 [http-bio-8077-exec-9] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={fl=*&sort=lastName_sortable+asc&start=0&q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&facet.limit=-1&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=2} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
2705879 [http-bio-8077-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr-example path=/select params={q=%2B(%2B((%2B(entryClassName:com.liferay.portal.model.User)+%2B(status:0)+%2B(organizationCount:0))))+%2BcompanyId:10159&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=0} hits=2 status=0 QTime=0
```

Also,
  If we add new *Web Content Article*, it is not reflected in the page, even though it is updated in the DB. It can only be viewed after restarting both the servers.

Similarly,
If I delete a private page from a site I get these errors on liferay console and gets a message
*"Site Pages is temporarily unavailable."*

The page wont get deleted.

**Lifeary error log**

```
14:08:55,711 WARN  [http-bio-8087-exec-8][ProxyMessageListener:81] com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchException
com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchException
        at com.liferay.portal.search.solr.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.search.solr.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:139)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyRequest.execute(ProxyRequest.java:85)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyMessageListener.receive(ProxyMessageListener.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.SynchronousDestination.send(SynchronousDestination.java:41)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.sender.DirectSynchronousMessageSender.send(DirectSynchronousMessageSender.java:54)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.BaseMultiDestinationProxyBean.synchronousSend(BaseMultiDestinationProxyBean.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.messaging.proxy.MultiDestinationMessagingProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(MultiDestinationMessagingProxyInvocationHandler.java:50)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy279.search(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchEngineUtil.search(SearchEngineUtil.java:591)
        at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.util.MBMessageIndexer.doDelete(MBMessageIndexer.java:224)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BaseIndexer.delete(BaseIndexer.java:138)
        at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBThreadLocalServiceImpl.deleteThread(MBThreadLocalServiceImpl.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.deleteThread(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBThreadLocalServiceImpl.deleteThread(MBThreadLocalServiceImpl.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.deleteThread(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.deleteDiscussionMessages(MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.java:503)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.deleteDiscussionMessages(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.deleteLayout(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:615)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.doDeleteLayout(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:512)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.deleteLayout(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.deleteLayout(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:125)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:159)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.deleteLayout(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutServiceImpl.deleteLayout(LayoutServiceImpl.java:323)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.deleteLayout(Unknown Source)

------------------------------------------------------

14:08:55,781 ERROR [http-bio-8087-exec-8][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchException
        at com.liferay.portal.search.solr.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.search.solr.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:139)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyRequest.execute(ProxyRequest.java:85)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyMessageListener.receive(ProxyMessageListener.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.SynchronousDestination.send(SynchronousDestination.java:41)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.sender.DirectSynchronousMessageSender.send(DirectSynchronousMessageSender.java:54)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.BaseMultiDestinationProxyBean.synchronousSend(BaseMultiDestinationProxyBean.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.messaging.proxy.MultiDestinationMessagingProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(MultiDestinationMessagingProxyInvocationHandler.java:50)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchEngineUtil.search(SearchEngineUtil.java:591)
        at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.util.MBMessageIndexer.doDelete(MBMessageIndexer.java:224)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BaseIndexer.delete(BaseIndexer.java:138)
        at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBThreadLocalServiceImpl.deleteThread(MBThreadLocalServiceImpl.java:158)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any specific custom clustering configurations, you don't need to configure the values for

```
net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/custom_cache/hibernate-clustered.xml
ehcache.multi.vm.config.location=/custom_cache/liferay-multi-vm-clustered.xml
```

any more in 6.2. *If* you configure them, you *must* make sure that your classpath actually has the `/custom_cache/*` files that you reference and that they're correct. You should try with the default values first (e.g. remove these two lines)

Your `dl.store.file.system.root.dir` looks like it works only on the same server - it must point to the same physical directory for both nodes (e.g. can be a mapped network drive. Disregard this remark if it actually is)

Both nodes must point to the same database.

Without further configuration, both nodes will use multicast to detect each other. If Multicast is deactivated on the network, they can't communicate and you must explicitly set up unicast communication. The log entries should tell you if the other nodes are found successfully.

Note that GA4 is out - in case you're running into a bug, it might long be fixed in the latest release.

Also, you don't seem to synchronize your lucene search index (or are you using SOLR?) This can cause similar issues to the ones that you describe.

In order to try further, you should go to Control Panel / Server Administration and try "reindex search indexes" as well es "clear caches" buttons. Depending on which one succeeds for you: Continue on the related configuration.

Comment: The problem which I'm facing is with the search indexer. I used solr 5.1.0 , and deployed solr4-web-6.2.0.3.war  to all the cluster nodes. But now I'm getting a 

 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.search.solr.SolrIndexSearcherImpl. It seems that solr4-web-6.2.0.3.war and solr5.0.1 wont sync in well.  Is there a way to make it work

Comment: if you're using this plugin: https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/36322550 it clearly states "This app uses Apache SOLR 4.3.1 libraries and is compatible with deployments using Solr 4.3.1 through Solr 4.10.2." - thus no luck with SOLR 5. Can you make it work? Probably (source is available, effort unknown). Will it run without any changes? Probably not. Might be easier to use SOLR 4

Comment: Hi Olaf, The Liferay 6.2-ce-ga2 + solr4-web-6.2.0.3.war and solr-4.3.1 combination worked, however i guess there is some problem with the schema.xml. i used the default schema.xml from solr4-web-6.2.0.3.war in both solr instance and liferay nodes and got these errors---org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id ------and-------com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchException: undefined field entryClassName